# Looking for full spoilers for the Shadowrun CCG

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for full-text (or even better, image) spoilers for the old Shadowrun collectible card game (interchangeably known as Shadowrun TCG or CCG).  Basically, I'm looking for a list of all the cards, plus their rules in one convenient package.

There used to be a Geocities site that had them, but the site is long gone now, so I wondered if anyone knows of another site that might have them.  I've done a fair amount of searching, and nothing has come up yet, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *exactly* what I'm looking for (I was preferring some sort of spreadsheet or document), but a software program called [Card Vault](http://www.wolflair.com/index.php?context=card_vault) (which allows you to create deck lists for games) has a Shadowrun module which can be downloaded [here](http://www.wolflair.com/rightframe.php?context=card_vault&page=supplemental_downloads).

The program allows you to download small images of the cards, and has spoilers for the core set, 2nd print, Underworld expansion, plus promos.  I've seen a few typos, and some incorrect rarities, but the overall it's pretty solid.

I might make an Excel spreadsheet and/or XML and/or Word document spoiler based on this, and if I do, I'll update the answer here with a link here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one link to start you on your way: a [full text spoiler in PDF](http://hem.passagen.se/kromange/srtcg/uwspoiler.pdf) for the "Underworld" expansion, which was the only one released for the game.

Comment: @Jadsac -- Yeah, I should have mentioned that was the one thing I *did* find.  I'm more interested in the core set than the Underworld set.  I *think* I might have found something, I'll update later